# How to copy stored "specific cells" in an Array? An alternative for range for each (loop)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy/paste through arrays for faster runtime, instead of range copy/paste.

I found this online and manipulated the code. It worked for copying by column.

**How do I get specific cells in a column, instead of the entire column based on (cell address) or (cell.offset.value)** without using a for each loop?

```vb
Dim MyBook As Workbook
Set MyBook = GetWorkbook("C:\Users\VV\Desktop\Source.xlsb")
         
Dim a, b(), i As Long, ii As Long, n As Long
         
With BayanBook.Sheets(1)
    a = .Range("a1", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value 'Resize(, 1).Value
End With
         
ReDim b(1 To UBound(a, 1) + UBound(a, 1) * UBound(a, 2), 1 To 1)
For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
    For ii = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
        n = n + 1
        b(n, 1) = a(i, ii)
    Next
    'n = n + 1
Next
         
With ThisWorkbook
   .Sheets(2).Range("a1").Resize(n).Value = b
End With
        
'If Not MyBook Is Nothing Then
    'MyBook.Close savechanges:=False
'End If
```

This is the function used for GetWorkbook (not related to topic):

```vb
Public Function GetWorkbook(ByVal sFullName As String) As Workbook
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim wbReturn As Workbook
        
    sFile = Dir(sFullName)
        
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wbReturn = Workbooks(sFile)
        
    If wbReturn Is Nothing Then
        Set wbReturn = Workbooks.Open(sFullName)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
        
    Set GetWorkbook = wbReturn
End Function
```

Comment: `I am trying to copy/paste through arrays for faster runtime, instead of range copy/paste.` If you are just copy pasting then `range copy/paste` would be faster and the code is of 1 line. `rngA.copy rngB`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I am trying to copy specific cells within those columns without using for each loop, that's why i am using arrrays.

Comment: Still `rngA.copy rngB` would be faster. For example `Range("A6:A9").Copy Range("D1")` OR `Range("A6:A9,A13:A16,A20:A23").Copy Range("D1")`. If this is not what you want then you may want to give an example of what you want to copy?

Comment: How do you want to specify which cells in the column to copy?   Where do you want them to - into a contiguous range in the destination,  or into the equivalent rows as from the source? Please add some sample data and the expected output

Comment: Hi chris, I want to specify the cells in the column by matching (cell.address) or by matching (cell.offset(0,-1).value) like if a primary key match in first column then copy those sepcific cells in that column. Then I want to paste them to the same related primary key offset in another workbook (related/contiguous)

Comment: So I have four tables in four different workbooks, each table has a unique identifier for each user (i.e. column A has username (user1, user2, etc...) each one of those users fill information based on his/her visible range. so i am trying to copy and paste each of those users' values within the same column (i.e. Column B) without using for each but with arrays only

Comment: Hi Siddharth, I have 3 tables filled by three users, then another 4th table by a 4th user. all tables have the same structure and field names. column A in all tables has usernames (1,2,3,...) each one of them fill the second column B with specific data based on their visible range. The logic is for each cell in column a if username in table 1 matches user name in table 4 then get cell.offset(0,1).value from table 1 to table 4 and so on. I want to do that by using arrays not for each loop just for performance

Comment: Are you sure this is not a job for `Vlookup`?

Comment: Please note 1) when replying to someone  use @username.  I only found your reply by change.  2) to add new information,  add it to your question, not as a comment. 3) Sample data is useful.   Together with a description of the required result.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I am sorry, don't know the procedures. Please refer to my same question with examples here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65060015/excel-vba-how-to-loop-through-cells-based-on-a-primary-key-value-and-header-nam